# How can I pass an enivironment variable into a nixos buildFHSUserEnv?

Tags: nixos

I have a Javascript build environment that I have recently wrapped the build command (`yarn` in this case, instead of `npm`) in an FHS environment. This was necessary because for this build, `yarn` pulls down several binary dependencies that aren't compatible with the NixOS filesystem, so wrapping the entire build process in an FHS environment has been beneficial.

However, we have one environment variable that I need to be able to pass to yarn to adjust the build process as I go. How can I pass that in on the command line?

My yarn environment file looks like this:

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixos> {}
, fetchurl ? pkgs.fetchurl
, nodejs ? pkgs.nodejs
, buildFHS ? pkgs.buildFHSUserEnv
, mkDerivation ? pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation
}:
let
    version = "0.19.1";
    pkgUrl = "https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/v${version}/yarn-v${version}.tar.gz";
    pkgSha = "751e1c0becbb2c3275f61d79ad8c4fc336e7c44c72d5296b5342a6f468526d7d";
in rec {
    yarn-env = mkDerivation {
        name = "yarn-env";

        src = fetchurl {
            url = pkgUrl;
            sha256 = pkgSha;
        };

        phases = [ "unpackPhase" "installPhase" ];

        installPhase = ''
            mkdir -p $out
            cp -r * $out
        '';

    };
    yarn = buildFHS {
        name = "yarn";
        targetPkgs = pkgs: [ nodejs
                             yarn-env
                             pkgs.git
                             pkgs.stack
                             pkgs.haskell.compiler.ghc802
                             pkgs.zlib
                             pkgs.ncurses5
                             pkgs.gmp
                             pkgs.neovim 
                             ];
        runScript = "yarn";
        profile="export DEPENDENCY_BRANCH=2310-nifty-unmerged-feature";
    };
}
```

So, I include this file in a larger `shell.nix` so that I have the yarn command around, and so I have several other commands that we use in build and deployment.

I would like to be able to specify that dependency branch on my command line instead of in the `yarn-env.nix` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `nix-shell` and `nix-build` support passing in arguments with `--arg` and `--argstr`. `--arg` will get evaluated as a nix expression and `--argstr` will get treated as a string literal.
Using the expression provided in the question you could use those to override the value of `pkgs` as follows:

```
nix-shell -A yarn --arg pkgs 'import /home/me/nixpkgs {}'
```

You could add another argument to your expression representing the dependency branch:

```
branch ? "2310-nifty-unmerged-feature"
```

and reference it within the expression with:

```
profile="export DEPENDENCY_BRANCH=${branch}";
```

The branch can then be passed in on command line with either:

```
nix-shell --arg branch \"somebranch\"
nix-shell --argstr branch somebranch
```

With that in place it should be a matter of adjusting the outer expressions in a similar manner and making them propagate the `branch` argument.

`nix-shell` manual page has more details about handling of `--arg` and `--argstr`.